# How to make animated header to show in mobile phones and tablets?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

I have a problem with the view on mobile phone and tablets, i want the banner to show animation in mobile phones, i know that flash won't work for that for sure, so what alternative is there to make this possible, and maybe long so i think GIF also won't work.

any ideas?

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: You might find this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172626/how-can-html5-replace-flash) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another great option for mobile and desktop alike is the WOW slider, which is a jquery plugin you can add to a page pretty simply:

http://wowslider.com/

If you have a specific question on how to implement a slideshow, post back for more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can animate a banner using normal UIImageView animation methods, cocos2d or HTML5. You can also use CoreAnimation. If you want to understand how to animate it, do add some details to the question.

Comment: HTML5 is not an option because if you add a video to animate that header you need to press play on the iOS it's not a video to be run within the browser but in the video player of iOS, as for the others yes please do tell how to implement, i have a SWF file or about 15 images with text over the image... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageView` and Split the gif file into several parts and then apply animation to it or [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif)

Comment: don't understand how to make this work with PHP/JS ... etc , not really android expert :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Through the use of the jQuery framework, you should be able to google and find various plug-ins that can help animate your header, even on mobile devices.  If you learn the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), you can also animate most HTML element blocks on both desktop and mobile device platforms.

Comment: check this out. they have a free version to the wowslider.  Simply load the code into your web site in the form of a banner and set certain options they provide. - http://wowslider.com/ajax-jquery-slider-pulse-blinds-demo.html?affid=331J-S9