# How to embed a 360 picture in swf format in a html website?

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

I've been trying to embed a 360 degree visualization in an html website. So far nothing worked. It's a swf file. Interesting thing is I can open the file only by Internet Explorer browser; nothing is shown on Firefox.

[Here](https://send.firefox.com/download/528393ca10ebe4e2/#DJhxGwQ9LiEXq9yQY8R85g) is the swf file.

I've tried simply to drag and drop in Adobe Dreamweaver. I've tried also swfobject-master.

Comment: Try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/137332/10122542

Answer (score 1):

Flash is essentially decommissioned in most browsers because it is coming to the end of life next year.

https://techcrunch.com/2017/07/25/get-ready-to-say-goodbye-to-flash-in-2020/

https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/06/chrome-76-flash-block-and-making-flash-use-more-annoying/

You'll have to find a new way to display your 360 visualization, such as Unity, HTML5, or one of probably dozens of other ways to do it now.

[How can HTML5 "replace" Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172626/how-can-html5-replace-flash)

Comment: computercarguy is right.  Here's a solution specific to you.  I just googled `360 panorama html5`:  https://pannellum.org/  There are very likely many other options for your 360 pano.